# operator changing the argument of class for no reason (*int)

Tags: c++, class, pointers, operator-overloading, arguments

In my class File, I've:

```
class File
{
    std::vector<char> name, timeOfCreation, timeOfLastEdit, content;
    std::vector<char>::const_iterator* pPos, *pPosOfEnd;
    int *pSize;
    bool *pForcedSize;
    void setTimeOfLastEdit();
    int* indexOfLastChar, *indexOfCurrentChar;

    friend class Interface;
    friend class Directory;
public:
    File(std::string, int argSize = 0, std::string arg_content = 0); // constructor
    File(); // constructor
    File(const File&); // copy constructor
    ~File(); // destructor
    char* returnName(); 

    File& operator = (const File&);
    File operator += (const int);
    File operator -= (const int);
    File& operator ++ (); // prefix
    File& operator -- (); // prefix
    File operator ++ (int); // postfix
    File operator -- (int); // postfix

    bool operator ! ();

    int operator () (char*, int);

    friend  bool operator == (const File&, const File&);
    friend  bool operator != (const File&, const File&);
    friend  bool operator >= (const File&, const File&);
    friend  bool operator <= (const File&, const File&);
    friend  bool operator < (const File&, const File&);
    friend  bool operator > (const File&, const File&);

    friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream&, File&);
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream&, File);

};
```

and my operator () is like this:

```
int File::operator () (char* contentNextNBytes, int n)
{
    int i; int j = 0;
    std::vector<char>::const_iterator it = content.begin();
    for(j = 0; j < *indexOfCurrentChar; j++)
        ++it;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        contentNextNBytes[i] = *it;
        if(i == *indexOfLastChar-1) 
        {
            contentNextNBytes[i+1] = '\0';
            *indexOfCurrentChar = i+1;
            return i+1;
        }
        ++it;
    }

    contentNextNBytes[i] = '\0';
    *indexOfCurrentChar = n;
    return n;
}
```

In my other class, Interface, I call the operator () with `int i = dir[index](buffer, n)`, where n is num of bytes, and index is the index of the File in directory.

Now, as is implemented in the operator, the value *indexOfCurrentChar points to should (and does) become the position of the last character extracted from the File. However when I call the same operator again, for the same index, with `int j = dir[index](buffer, n1)`, right when the program enters the operator {} it changes the value of *indexOfCurrentChar to 0 again, while my code should continue from the last char and read the next n1 bytes in File

Why does this happen? :(

Here's part of the code I'm using to call the operator in the class Interface:

```
 buffer = new char[n+1];
    k = d[index](buffer, n);
    std::cout<<"Extracting of "<<k<<" bytes succeeded, and here is the content extracted:\n";
std::cout<<"\""<<buffer<<"\"";
```

Edit1: Here's where I change my indexOfCurrentChar:

1) In the assignment operator =   (however, I'm not calling it in my Interface class)
2) In the copy constructor  (Also not using it in Interface class, and it just copies the value)
3) In the File constructor:

```
File::File()
{
    // stuff
    indexOfCurrentChar = new int;
} //I'm not setting its value, just allocating memory
```

4) In the File constructor:

```
File::File(std::string arg_name, int arg_size, std::string arg_content)
{
     // stuff
     indexOfCurrentChar = new int;
     *indexOfCurrentChar = 0;
    //setting it to 0, but its just at creation time
}
```

5) In the >> operator
//getting file content

```
std::cout<<"Enter file content: ";
    *object.indexOfCurrentChar = 0;
    while( in.get(c) && c != '\n');
    i = 0;
    in.get(c);
    if(*(object.pSize) == 0)
    {
        while(c != '\n')
        {
            object.content.push_back(c);
            in.get(c);  
            ++i;
        }
        *(object.pSize) = (int)object.content.size();
        *(object.pPosOfEnd) = object.content.end();
        *object.indexOfLastChar = i;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
        std::vector<char>::const_iterator it = object.content.begin();
        while(c != '\n')
        {
            if(i == *object.pSize)
            {
                *object.pPosOfEnd = it;
                *object.indexOfLastChar = i;
            }
            if(i >= *object.pSize)
            {
                in.get(c);
                continue;
            }
            object.content.push_back(c);
            in.get(c);
            ++i;
        }
    }


    *(object.pPos) = object.content.begin();
```

And thats it :)

Aaaaand although I'm sorry to show this to the world, here's my ugly Interface class method. All of my program input/output is managed through Interface.writeOutput method, which is here:

```
Interface::Interface()
{
    menu = new char*[12];
    menu[0] = "Welcome, please select an option from the following, by pressing the respective numbers:";
    menu[1] = "1  Create a Directory\n2  Create a single File\n3  Exit program";
    menu[2] = "Ok, now please select a further option:";
    menu[3] = "Enter the number of Files you want to import: ";
    menu[4] = "Enter the files...";
    menu[5] = "1  Write out the Directory details\n2  Extract N bytes from a desired file\n3  Remove a file with desired name from the Directory\n4  Write content of a file\n0  Go back to the beginning";
    menu[6] = "Enter the index of the file: ";
    menu[7] = "Enter how many bytes to extract: ";
    menu[8] = "Content of the extracted bytes: ";
    menu[9] = "Enter the name of the file: ";
    menu[10] = "What do you want to do next?";
    menu[11] = "Please enter a regular number...";
}


void Interface::writeMenu()
{
    Error e;
    char c, tmp[5], name[30];
    int n, k, index, i, numDir;
    char *buffer; 
    int *haveReadFiles;

    std::cout<<menu[0];
    std::cout<<"\n\n";
startMenu: 
    std::cout<<menu[1];
    std::cout<<"\n\n";
    std::cin>>c;
    if((!isdigit(c)) || ( c != '1' && c!= '2' && c!='3'))
    {
        std::cout<<"\n"<<menu[11]<<"\n\n";
        goto startMenu;
    }
    if(c == '1')
    {
        std::cout<<"Enter the name of the directory: ";
        std::cin>>name;
        Directory d(name);
        std::cout<<"\n\n\nEnter number of files of directory: ";
        std::cin>>numDir;
        haveReadFiles = new int[numDir];
        if(!haveReadFiles)
        {
            e.writeToOutput(7);
            exit(1);
        }

        for(i = 0; i < numDir; i++)
        {
        haveReadFiles[i] = 0;   
            //std::cin.ignore(5,'\n');
        //  std::cin.ignore ( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
            File f;
            std::cin>>f;
            d += f;
        }

    menu1:
        std::cout<<"\n\n"<<menu[2]<<"\n\n";
menuRepeat:
        std::cout<<menu[5];
        std::cout<<"\n\n";
        std::cin>>c;
        if(!isdigit(c) || (c != '1' && c!= '2' && c!='3' && c != '4' && c != '0'))
        {
            std::cout<<"\n"<<menu[11];
            goto menu1;
        }
        switch(c)
        {
        case '0': goto startMenu;break;
        case '1': std::cout<<d;break;
        case '2': 
            {
                menu2:
                std::cout<<"\n\n"<<menu[6];

                std::cin>>tmp;
                for(i = 0; i < (int)strlen(tmp); i++)
                    if(!isdigit(tmp[i]))
                    {
                        std::cout<<"\n\n"<<menu[11];
                        goto menu2;
                    }
                index = atoi(tmp);
                menu3:
                std::cout<<"\n\n"<<menu[7];
                std::cin>>tmp;
                for(i = 0; i < (int)strlen(tmp); i++)
                    if(!isdigit(tmp[i]))
                    {
                        std::cout<<"\n\n"<<menu[11];
                        goto menu3;     
                    }
                n = atoi(tmp);


                buffer = new char[n+1];
                k = d[index](buffer, n);
                std::cout<<"Extracting of "<<k<<" bytes succeeded, and here is the content extracted:\n";
                std::cout<<"\""<<buffer<<"\"";
            } break;
        case '3':
            {
                std::cout<<"\n\nEnter the name of the file: ";
                std::cin>>name;
                d -= name;
                std::cout<<"...file removed!\n";
                std::cout<<"Directory without the removed file looks like this: \n\n"<<d;
            }break;
        case '4': 
            {
                menuFF:
                std::cout<<"\n\nEnter the index of the desired file: ";
                std::cin>>tmp;
                for(i = 0; i < (int)strlen(tmp); i++)
                    if(!isdigit(tmp[i]))
                    {
                        std::cout<<"\n\n"<<menu[11];
                        goto menuFF;
                    }
                index = atoi(tmp);
                std::cout<<"\nHere's the content:\n";
                File ff = d[index];
                std::vector<char>::const_iterator iter = ff.content.begin();
                for(; iter < ff.content.end(); ++iter)
                {
                    std::cout<<*iter;
                }
                std::cout<<"\n\n";
            }
        }
        menu4:
        std::cout<<"\n\nWhat do you want to do now?\n\n1  Exit program\n2  Go back to start menu\n3  Do more stuff with your Directory\n\n";
        std::cin>>c;
        if((!isdigit(c)) || ( c != '1' && c!= '2' && c!='3'))
        {
            std::cout<<"\n"<<menu[11];
            goto menu4;
        }
        if(c=='1')
        {
            "Thank you, goodbye...";
            exit(0);
        }
        if(c=='2')
            goto startMenu;
        if(c=='3')
            goto menuRepeat;
    }
    else if(c=='2')
    {
        std::cout<<"Enter your file...\n";
        File g;
        std::cin>>g;
        menuZZ:
        std::cout<<"\n\nHere's what you can do with your file: \n\n1  Extract N bytes of content from it\n2  Write its content out\n3  Write its properties out\n4  Return to start menu\n\n";
        std::cin>>c;
        switch(c)
        {
        case '1':
            {

                menuYY:
                std::cout<<"\n\n"<<menu[7];
                std::cin>>tmp;
                for(i = 0; i < (int)strlen(tmp); i++)
                    if(!isdigit(tmp[i]))
                    {
                        std::cout<<"\n\n"<<menu[11];
                        goto menuYY;        
                    }
                n = atoi(tmp);
                buffer = new char[n+1];
                k = g(buffer, n);
                std::cout<<"Extracting of "<<k<<" bytes succeeded, and here is the content extracted:\n";
                std::cout<<"\""<<buffer<<"\"";
                std::cout<<"\n\n";
                goto startMenu;
            } break;
        case'2':
            {
                std::vector<char>::const_iterator it = g.content.begin();
                for(; it < g.content.end(); ++it)
                {
                    std::cout<<*it;
                }
                std::cout<<"\n\n";
            }
        case'3':
            {
                std::cout<<g<<"\n\n";
                goto startMenu;
            } break;
        case'4': 
            {
                std::cout<<"\n\n";
                goto startMenu;
            } break;
        default:
            {
                std::cout<<menu[11];
                goto menuZZ;    
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Thank you, goodbye... ";
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

Last but not least, the `Directory::operator [] implementation`:

In header: `File& operator [] (int);`

Implementation:

```
 File& Directory::operator [] (int index)
{
    std::vector<File>::const_iterator i = arr.begin();
    for(int j = 0; j < index; ++j)
        ++i;
    File* temp = new File;
    *temp = *i;
    return *temp;
    delete temp;
}
```

enjoy ^^

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same index the second time?

Comment: Did you change what `*indexOfcurrentChar` points to somewhere in between your two `operator()` calls?

Comment: @Meysam Yeah, considering it writes out content correctly, just does it from the beginning, while it should do it from the end of previous extraction

Comment: @Tony The Lion I'm quite sure I haven't, but I suppose that's what's happening somewhere in the code, maybe due to operator [], but i doubt it...

Comment: Show us where you assign a value to `indexOfCurrentChar` and `indexOfLastChar`.

Comment: You need to post more of your code to show what happens in between the two calls.

Comment: Also, if you are compiling on Linux, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is your friend.

Comment: in the constructor, indexOfCurrentChar = 0 should be changed to *indexOfCurrentChar = 0

Comment: @Meysam yeah of course, I just mistyped here, in the code its *indexOfCurrentChar = 0. As for the rest of the code, it's written in the Interface class, which is disgusting to look at, all in one method with thousands of cases and gotos... i can still show it of course

Comment: Aren't you calling `>> operator` before calling `() operator` the second time?

Comment: uhm I don't think so, it calls it just once, then the `goto` returns below the `>>`, so it doesn't execute again. The `Directory d` I create stays the same throughout that branch of code I think... (I mean obviously it doesn't, but I rly don't see it)

Comment: If you show us a complete example of code that reproduces the error, we will have a chance of finding the cause. If you minimize that code before posting it, you will make our job much easier, and maybe spot the bug yourself.

Comment: well technically it's not an error, it just always starts extracting bytes from the beginning of the File.. I'll try to minimize the code and post it asap..

Comment: Please post the implementation of `Directory::operator[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the problem is with the `Directory` class and the way that it stores and returns `File` objects.  For example, if `Directory::operator[]` returns a `File` instead of a `File &`, then any changes made to the returned object will not be persisted to the `Directory`'s internal copy of it, so making two calls in a row like

```
int i = dir[index](buffer, n);
int j = dir[index](buffer, n1);
```

actually causes `File::operator()` to be called on two different temporary `File` objects.  This could explain why the value of `*indexOfCurrentChar` is not what you expect.

**EDIT**

Now that you've shown the implementation of `Directory::operator[]`, I can confidently say that my suspicions were correct.  Even though you changed the signature of `Directory::operator[]` so that it returns a `File &` now, your implementation still won't behave the way you want it to because it doesn't return a reference to the correct `File` object (the `Directory` object's internal copy of it).  The three statements

```
File* temp = new File;
*temp = *i;
return *temp;
```

create a new copy of the `Directory` object's internal `File` object and return a reference to that, so any changes made to the returned `File` object's member variables aren't reflected in the corresponding entry of the `Directory::arr` vector.  Since `vector::operator[]` returns a reference, changing the body of `Directory::operator[]` to simply

```
return arr[index];
```

should give you the desired behavior.

I should probably also note that your current implementation of `Directory::operator[]` leaks memory: `delete temp;` never runs because `return *temp;` causes control to leave the function.

Comment: No, I tested this, it's not the cause of problem.

Comment: @Meysam How could you have tested this?  Do you have the source for the `Directory` class?

Comment: You are right. My assumption was that `dir` is an array of `File` objects. The implementation of `operator[]` matters here as you said :)

Comment: Actually, I'm fairly certain now that this is the problem, based on the definition of the `Directory` class shown in one of the poster's [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263150/program-not-calling-the-right-overloaded-operator).

Comment: @chess007 Yeah it returned just File, should it be like this?

`File& Directory::operator [] (int index)
{
 std::vector<File>::const_iterator i = arr.begin();
 for(int j = 0; j < index; ++j)
  ++i;
 File* temp = new File;
 *temp = *i;
 return *temp;
 delete temp;
}`

I've changed the `[]` operator to return `File&` but the problem persists.. do you think it returns a reference properly now?

Comment: @Vidak I edited my answer to take this new information into account

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend replacing

```
 if(i == *indexOfLastChar-1)
```

with

```
 if(i == (*indexOfLastChar)-1)
```

I think you are reading the value priorto 'indexOfLastChar' and compare that that to i.

Comment: just did it, unfortunately it's still the same thing :(

Comment: dereference operator (*) is evaluated before subtraction operator (-), and subtraction operator is evaluated before == operator. So I think this change would make no difference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: *indexOfCurrentChar = n; /* should not it be */ *indexOfCurrentChar += n;

Answer (score 0):

I've posted this one as a comment, but I think

```
indexOfCurrentChar = n;
```

should be

```
 *indexOfCurrentChar += n;
```

Comment: yeah it should thanks, but it doesn't fix my current problem :(